# Problems setting up Watson Speech to Text API in Javascript / Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to set up Watson Speech to Text to work in my Node.Js app.

First, I set up the server side in my `app.js` file to fetch the token (this is in addition to setting the `express` server up, which I omit):

```
const AuthorizationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/authorization/v1');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
const TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
const vcapServices = require('vcap_services');

// speech to text token endpoint
var sttAuthService = new AuthorizationV1(
  Object.assign(
    {
      username: MY_IBM_APP_USERNAME, // or hard-code credentials here
      password: MY_IBM_APP_PASSWORD
    },
    vcapServices.getCredentials('speech_to_text') // pulls credentials from environment in bluemix, otherwise returns {}
  )
);
app.use('/api/speech-to-text/token', function(req, res) {
  sttAuthService.getToken(
    {
      url: SpeechToTextV1.URL
    },
    function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error retrieving token: ', err);
        res.status(500).send('Error retrieving token');
        return;
      }
      res.send(token);
    }
  );
});
```

(The above is the example from [IBM Speech Javascript SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/server.js))

Then in the actual server-side file I have the following code to first fetch the token and to the activate voice input (following the [example here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/static/microphone-streaming.html)):

```
              fetch('/api/speech-to-text/token')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function (token) {

  var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
      token: token,
      outputElement: '#statement' // CSS selector or DOM Element to put the text in
  });

  stream.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });

  document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
    stream.stop();
  };

}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

However, on Chrome I get an error "failed to construct web socket" and on Safari I simply get 404 error for `/api/speech-to-text/token` which is supposed to get the token.

What am I doing wrong? Where the error?

Thank you!

Comment: I have a quick question - are you writing a browser-side application? Or are you just using this browser code because of the example? If you are writing server-only Node code, the implementation would be more simple

Comment: @dpopp07 Yes, it's a browser-side implementation as I would like the voice to be recognized when people are using the app. You can see what it's about on http://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus — there you will find both the server-side app.js and the views/entries.ejs file I use for the frontend. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem - it seems that the example was using an older version of `watson-developer-cloud` that contained a bug.

Updating to the newest version of `watson-developer-cloud` (v3.12.0) fixed the issue for me.